# TSQL Calculate difference between oldest and newest row

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to display how much a user's scores have changed between their oldest and most recent entries.

Given data:

```
Timestamp           |    Score    |  User 
2021-08-25 10:22:00 |    1300     |   A
2021-08-24 09:38:00 |    1451     |   A
2021-08-21 21:53:00 |    1381     |   B
2021-08-21 17:17:00 |    1129     |   B
2021-08-24 14:32:00 |    1278     |   A
2021-08-21 13:21:00 |    1401     |   B
```

I want to produce an output that looks like:

```
User  | CurrentScore |    Change   |   Timestamp
  A   |     1300     |     -151    |   2021-08-25 10:22:00
  B   |     1381     |     -19     |   2021-08-21 21:53:00
```

I can display the oldest row and the newest row, but I struggle to bring the two together in a single output row with a calculated column.  Any help is apprecriated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if this fit your needs, and please next time instead of describing the table provide DDL+DML (Queries to create the table and insert some sample data)

### DDL+DML : should have being provided by the OP!

```
CREATE TABLE QQ(
    [Timestamp] DATETIME2,
    Score INT,
    [User] VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT QQ([Timestamp],Score,[User]) VALUES
('2021-08-25 10:22:00',1300,'A'),
('2021-08-24 09:38:00',1451,'A'),
('2021-08-21 21:53:00',1381,'B'),
('2021-08-21 17:17:00',1129,'B'),
('2021-08-24 14:32:00',1278,'A'),
('2021-08-21 13:21:00',1401,'B')
GO
```

### Solution

```
;With MyCTE as (
    SELECT [user], Score, 
        [Timestamp] = FIRST_VALUE ([Timestamp]) OVER (PARTITION BY [user] ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC), 
        FirstScore = FIRST_VALUE (Score) OVER (PARTITION BY [user] ORDER BY [Timestamp]), 
        CurrentScore = FIRST_VALUE (Score) OVER (PARTITION BY [user] ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC)
    FROM QQ
) 
SELECT DISTINCT [user], CurrentScore, Change = CurrentScore - FirstScore, [Timestamp]
FROM MyCTE
GO
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep in mind adding DDL+DML next time I have a SQL question.  I wasn't aware of protocols for questions around SQL Server.

Comment: You are most welcome `:-)`

Comment: You should use `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` in case of duplicate timestamps. It's also more efficient